# I need some an error with Discord.js v12 and the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I keep getting this error every time I try to deploy my discord bot. I keep trying things but I was hoping someone with more experience than me.

The error:

```
                client.database?.init();
22:34:56.146                    ^
22:34:56.146    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
22:34:56.146        at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
22:34:56.146        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
22:34:56.146        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
22:34:56.146        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
22:34:56.146        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
22:34:56.146        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
22:34:56.146        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
22:34:56.150    Error: Command "node ." exited with 1
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (that `?` in `client.database?.init();`) is only available in Node.js v14, so make sure you're using the latest LTS (v14.15.4 at the moment).

You can download the latest version of Node.js from [their site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or even better, you could use a Node version manager (like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)) to manage multiple active Node versions.